# Use header tag in html

Tags: html, header, element

Why would one use `<header>` tags or `<footer>` or `<address>` tags? Is it just for SEO, or another reason?

I ask this question because IE8 and older doesn't support many of these elements.

Comment: My question is: why do you care about supporting IE8? There are also other reasons such as code readability and easier CSS styles.

Comment: many of reputable websites are compatible with ie at now and many user in the word using ie  (about 6.3%). I don't know whyyy? but they use it

Answer (score 1):

These are all tags introduced with HTML5. They are part of an evolution of HTML. They're not supported in IE8 because they were introduced after support for IE8 ended. They were introduced to provide more logical elements that were commonly used in web page designs.

If you need to support IE8, you can do so by not using these tags and sticking with `<div>` tags with classes, such as:

- `<div class="header"></div>`
- `<div class="footer"></div>`
- `<div class="address"></div>`

accompanied, of course, by CSS styles for each.

They have nothing to do with SEO.

Answer (score 0):

The tags you describe, such as a `header` tag, are what is known as 'syntactic sugar'. That is, it makes it easier to read and know what the intent of the tag is. This is good for human readers, but it is especially useful for automated systems.

Compare these examples that all could mean exactly the same thing:

```
<header>...</header>
<div class="header">...</div>
<div class="hdr">...</div>
```

Note that `header` is easy to differentiate from the two `div` tags. Only if you know what the `class` attribute means will you understand what the `div` tags are defining. Because the `class` attribute value is free-form, it means there is no *standard* definition.

SEO is one example of an automated system that might need to read the tag directly and understand that it has a semantic meaning. A particularly observant SEO engine might understand that the above three tags all refer to the same semantic definition, but you will agree that writing an engine that would presciently know all three mean 'header' would be difficult. In fact, there is nothing to disambiguate the latter two from `<div class="zebra">`.

Having automated systems be able to read your code and understand the semantic meaning goes well beyond SEO: it can make automated handling of mobile versions easier, for instance. You no longer have to hand-roll code for your specific implementation. You can use Javascript libraries that might do handy things with your headers, such as allow them to be sortable or auto-link them. Anyone writing those libraries has an easier time doing it.

You also ask why you would use something not supported by older browsers that are still widely used. That is a question of demographic: what is your app targeting? If you need the 6% of the world that is using an old browser to utilize your application, then you should absolutely use backwards compatible techniques. If, on the other hand, you want to make the UX the best possible for a set of users likely to be using a modern browser, then you should use the new tags. (Note that having bad UX or long development time as you roll your own solutions to things may cost you more than 6% of your application's userbase...)